# Angular2 page refreshes when property is updated

Tags: angular

I am brand new to Angular2, and trying to understand why my page is refreshed then trying to set some properties from form data.

Here is the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Credentials } from './authentication/Credentials';
import { User } from './authentication/User';

@Component({
    selector: 'loginForm',
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/loginForm.component.html'
})
export class LoginForm {
    //user: User;
    credentials: Credentials;

    submitForm(form: any): void {

        this.credentials.username = form.username;
        this.credentials.password = form.password;

        console.log(form.username);
    }
}
```

If I comment out `this.credentials.username` and `this.credentials.password` lines, the submitted username is logged to the console.  As soon as those lines are uncommented (like above), the page completely re-renders (refreshes).

**EDIT:**

What I am really trying to do here is be able to authenticate the user without the refresh.  Here is the template as well:

```
<form #form="ngForm" class="navbar-form navbar-right" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" ngModel required>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" ngModel required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check it by binding the submitForm() to click event of button...

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="submitForm()">Log in</button>
```

Also remove ngSubmit from form